# What does "$A \cap B$ is a algebra. Moreover, the product map is continuous" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation

Let $A$ and $B$ be (Sobolev) vector spaces.

> $A \cap B$ is a algebra. Moreover, the product map is continuous.

What does this mean precisely? Is it: if $c_i \in A \cap B$ then $c_1c_2 \in A \cap B$, and $|c_1c_2| \leq |c_1||c_2|$, what's the norm?

(Here $A = W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ and $B=L^\infty$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The norm is, e.g., $\|\cdot\|_A + \|\cdot\|_B$.

Typically, this can be proven by a product rule. For example, in the case $s = 1$, $p = 2$ you have
$$(u \, v)' = u \, v' + u' \, v \in H^1 \cap L^\infty$$
for $u,v \in H^1 \cap L^\infty$. And this yields
$$\| (u \, v)' \|_{L^2} \le \|u\|_{L^\infty} \, \|v'\|_{L^2} + \|u'\|_{L^2} \, \|v\|_{L^\infty}.$$